# Missing soft link to linux source tree

Tags: linux, kernel, kernel-module

In /lib/modules/xx.xx.xx-xx there is supposed to be two soft links one called source and one called build. The source one is there and its fine but the build one is missing and I have no idea where it is supposed to point to and I need to install a driver for my video card. Is there any way to find out where that is supposed to point if so how and where. I know there are a lot of other questions out there but not of them actually discribe where they are supposed to be pointing in the end.

Updated the link and now it is having build errors that I can't fix because I can't even find the struct its talking about

```
make -C /lib/modules/3.16.0-4-amd64/build M=/home/gibsont/gpuTempDriver modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-4-amd64'
Makefile:10: *** mixed implicit and normal rules: deprecated syntax
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-4-amd64'
  CC [M]  /home/gibsont/gpuTempDriver/base.o
/home/gibsont/gpuTempDriver/base.c: In function ‘_rtl_init_mac80211’:
/home/gibsont/gpuTempDriver/base.c:319:6: error: ‘IEEE80211_HW_BEACON_FILTER’ undeclared (first use in this function)
      IEEE80211_HW_BEACON_FILTER |
      ^
/home/gibsont/gpuTempDriver/base.c:319:6: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
/home/gibsont/gpuTempDriver/base.c:349:4: error: ‘struct ieee80211_hw’ has no member named ‘channel_change_time’
  hw->channel_change_time = 100;
    ^
/home/gibsont/gpuTempDriver/base.c: In function ‘rtl_action_proc’:
/home/gibsont/gpuTempDriver/base.c:858:32: error: ‘struct ieee80211_conf’ has no member named ‘channel’
       rx_status.freq = hw->conf.channel->center_freq;
                                ^
/home/gibsont/gpuTempDriver/base.c:859:32: error: ‘struct ieee80211_conf’ has no member named ‘channel’
       rx_status.band = hw->conf.channel->band;
                                ^
/home/gibsont/gpuTempDriver/base.c:861:25: error: ‘RX_FLAG_MACTIME_MPDU’ undeclared (first use in this function)
       rx_status.flag |= RX_FLAG_MACTIME_MPDU;
                         ^
/home/gibsont/gpuTempDriver/base.c: In function ‘rtl_beacon_statistic’:
/home/gibsont/gpuTempDriver/base.c:1132:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘compare_ether_addr’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  if (compare_ether_addr(hdr->addr3, rtlpriv->mac80211.bssid))
  ^
/home/gibsont/gpuTempDriver/base.c: In function ‘rtl_send_smps_action’:
/home/gibsont/gpuTempDriver/base.c:1414:16: error: ‘struct <anonymous>’ has no member named ‘sta’
   info->control.sta = sta;
                ^
/home/gibsont/gpuTempDriver/base.c:1415:24: error: ‘struct ieee80211_conf’ has no member named ‘channel’
   info->band = hw->conf.channel->band;
                        ^
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-4-common/scripts/Makefile.build:262: recipe for target '/home/gibsont/gpuTempDriver/base.o' failed
make[4]: *** [/home/gibsont/gpuTempDriver/base.o] Error 1
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-4-common/Makefile:1350: recipe for target '_module_/home/gibsont/gpuTempDriver' failed
make[3]: *** [_module_/home/gibsont/gpuTempDriver] Error 2
Makefile:181: recipe for target 'sub-make' failed
make[2]: *** [sub-make] Error 2
Makefile:8: recipe for target 'all' failed
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-4-amd64'
Makefile:27: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I copied it from the disk because it was a read only and placed it into my home directory.

I feel like this has become a whole new issues or possibly the link is wrong and is causing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

this is mine:

```
2509142 lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root     37 Apr 24 15:02 build -> /usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-4-amd64
```

actually it's managed by package manager. I install linux headers using apt-get. I think you should do the same, unless you are advanced kernel developer.

Comment: I installed the linux headers and it didn't update or create the link but it did update the source link. I set up the link to the same directory as yours because that is the same version and cpu type that I have and now I'm geting some other build errors.

Comment: @nonprofitgibi it means your build is not complete. you should try to reinstall the header and see if there are some error messages.